# How to set-up my provided code for reactJS development?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, npm-scripts

I have been provided a code base which has reactJS included in chunks, it is not a complete reactJS project. I do not have much experience with webpacks, reactJS, nodeJS. Since there is no "start" command in "scripts" of package.json, it won't run the project. Upon opening index.html, all I see is the non-react part, the reactJS components are not showing on the browser. I will share with you my package.json and webpack.config.js files, please kindly let me know how to run it on node server.

Package.json:

```
"main": "webpack.config.js",
"scripts": {
    "build": "webpack && uglifyjs ./assets/build/postadd.js -c -m -o ./assets/build/postadd.min.js "
  }
```

webpack.config.js:

```
debug = process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production";
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    context: __dirname,
    devtool:  "inline-sourcemap" ,
    entry: {
        postadd: "./js/postadd/main.js",
        search: "./js/search/main.js"
    },
    output: {
        path: __dirname+ "/assets/build/",
        filename: "[name].js"
    }
```

There is no command in scripts other than "build". If you need any more details please let me know, I am stuck.

Comment: did you run the build command?

Comment: @azium yes I have run the build command and it is working, but my problem is to see the react components on the browser, which are not being shown.

Comment: once I can see the react components on my browser, I can then make changes to it